# Nonsymmetric matrix has real eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Consider a $n\times n$ symmetric matrix $A=\{a_{i,j}\}_{i,j}$ with nonnegative values, i.e., $a_{i,j}\ge0$. It is known that $A$ must have real eigenvalues. Now, consider numbers $s_1,\dots, s_n\ge0$. Is it true that $\{s_ia_{i,j}\}_{i,j}$ has real eigenvalues? For a better visualization of the matrix:
\begin{align*}
\{s_ia_{i,j}\}_{i,j}=\begin{bmatrix}
    s_1 a_{11} & s_1 a_{12} & s_1 a_{13} & \dots  & s_1 a_{1n} \\
    s_2 a_{21} & s_2 a_{22} & s_2 a_{23} & \dots  & s_2 a_{2n} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    s_n a_{n1} & s_n a_{n2} & s_n a_{n3} & \dots  & s_n a_{nn}.
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

In the two dimensional case $n=2$, it is not hard to see that indeed there cannot be complex eigenvalues. However, calculations become immediately very messy in the three dimensional case. Some numerical tests in the 3-dimensional case suggests the conjecture should be true.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, it is true.

If $S$ is the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $\sqrt{s_i}$, then your matrix is $S^2A$.  This has the same eigenvalues as $S A S$ (a consequence of the fact that $BC$ and $CB$ have the same eigenvalues for any square matrices $B$ and $C$), which is a real symmetric matrix, and therefore has real eigenvalues.